# Term to call a function with empty parameter

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, terminology, language-design

In functional programming, what is the correct name to call a function that accepts no arguments? For example:

```
// 2 types of execute functions
type Function =
    | UnitFunction of (unit -> unit)
    | OperandFunction of (unit16 -> unit)

let nop () =
    ()

let shiftRegisterA operand =
    registers.A <- registers.A <<< operand
```

Can `nop` be called a `UnitFunction`, and `shiftRegisterA` be called an `OperandFunction`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're referring here is generally called [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) of a function. Thus a function with no arguments would be called a nullary function and a function with a single argument - unary function.

While you can still use this terminology in context of F# functions and be universally understood, this is not entirely precise. F# functions always take a single argument and return a single value, by virtue of functions being curried by default.

In your case, `nop` has type `unit -> unit`. What this means is that it takes a single argument of type `unit` (the type's lone `()` value), and returns a result of type `unit`. That still makes it a unary function though.

Answer (score 2):

In assembly programming calling a function is the process of pushing parameters on the stack (or registers depending on the calling convention) then jumping to the address of the function.

In more high-level languages such as Java, C#, C and so on this process is more or less hidden to us. However, we see traces of it when we call functions that takes no parameters, ie `void`.

In functional programming languages such as F#, haskell and so on the concept of functions are closer to mathematical functions that produces an answer from a single input.

To see that all functions in F# accept a single input let's look at the following function:

```
// val f: (int*int) -> int
let f (x,y) = x + y
```

`f` accepts a pair of integers and produces an integer. The pair is from the perspective of `f` a single value that it deconstructs to produce the answer.

```
// val g: int -> int -> int
let g x y = x + y
```

This obviously seems like a function that accepts two integers to produce an integer but if we rewrite it slightly we see that is not necessarily the case:

```
// val h: int -> int -> int
let h x = fun y -> x + y
```

`h` is equivalent to `g` but here we see that `h` actually takes a single integer that produce a function that accepts an integer to produce an integer.

The `->` in the signature is right associative and we add parantheses we see more clearly that `g` and `h` are actually taking a single input.

```
// val g: int -> (int -> int)
let g x y = x + y

// val h: int -> (int -> int)
let h x = fun y -> x + y

let gx = g 1 2
let gy = (g 1) 2
let hx = h 1 2
let hy = (h 1) 2
```

In my opinion functions in F# are of a higher level of abstraction than functions in say C#/Java as C#/Java functions are conceptually closer to the assembly language function than what F# functions is.

Further, if every function requires a single argument it makes little sense for functions that accepts no argument.

But what about this function?

```
// val i: unit -> int
let i () = 3
```

Doesn't it accept no argument to produce 3? No, it accepts the unit value `()` which is only value in the type `unit`.

In Haskell they have a name for functions that accept `void` and produce an answer:

```
absurd :: Void -> a
```

A value could perhaps be seen as a function that takes no arguments but I am not a category theory expert.

Going back to example code:

```
type Function =
| UnitFunction of (unit -> unit)
| OperandFunction of (unit16 -> unit)
```

The functional approach would something like this:

```
type Abstraction =
| Concrete of obj
| Function of Abstraction -> Abstraction
```

Ie an `Abstraction` is either a value or a function.

Looking at the code it seems to emulate something that looks close to assembly language so in that case it's fine to think of functions as pushing parameters and jumping to an address.

```
type Function =
| VoidFunction    of (unit -> unit)
| UnaryFunction   of (unit16 -> unit)
| BinaryFunction  of (unit16 -> unit16 -> unit)
```

Hope this was interesting.

PS.

It seems like `unit` type is a small detail but IMO it enables many good things.

- No need for statements.
- Simplifies generic programming (the `void` case often requires a special case, consider `Task<'T>` and `Task`).
- Allows us to think of functions like mathematical functions rather than jumping to an address in memory.

Comment: Re: special `void` case, the most jarring one in C# is the split between `Action` and `Func` types.